# Fixed Points in Mobius Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, mobius-transformation

Let $$w(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{e^z+1}; \ z=x+iy$$ and $$w=u+iv$$ Then show that the image of the $y$-axis in the domain is $v$-axis in the co-domain. Does this contradict the result that a Mobius transformation with at least $3$ fixed points is a identity mapping ? Why ?

I have already proved the fact that $y$-axis is mapped onto $v$-axis by showing that
$$w(iy)=i\frac{\sin y}{1+\cos y}$$

Now I need to show that this mapping does not contradict the property of a Moebius transformation. For that I would either have to show that $$\frac{\sin y}{1+\cos y}=y$$ has less than $3$ solutions or that $w(z)$ is not a Moebius transformation. Which one is it and how do I prove that ?

Answer (score 1):

Your transformation is *not* a Mobius transformation.

Comment: Can you prove it ?

Comment: @Surb To show that this function is not Moebius then we would have to show that there does not exist any such a,b,c & d such that w(z)=az+b/cz+d. How do I do that ?

Comment: @Surb  Is Mobius transformation injective ? Because this function is definitely not injective

Comment: First, my comment previously had a mistake. I wanted to say that Moebius transformation are of the form $z\color{red}{\mapsto }\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ (where $ad-bc\neq 0$). Your function is obviously not a Moebius since it's not of this form. Why do you insist on thinking that it could be a Moebius transformation ? It is just like saying that $e^z$ is a polynomial... it just has no sens... @SiddharthPrakash

Comment: @Surb Because it was asked in my exam. And when you make a statement in math no matter how simple and trivial it seems you need to be able to prove it. So when you say it is not of the form (az+b)/(cz+d) you have to show that there does not exist any a,b,c &d in the complex plane which will satisfy the equality. Otherwise it is not a valid explanation. So it is better if we look for properties both the function don't have in common.

Answer (score 1):

A mobius transformation $w(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}, ad-bc\ne 0$ has a unique simple pole at $z=-d/c$ whereas in your problem there are infinite poles $z=(2k+1)i\pi, k=0,1,2,...$ so their equivalence in $\mathbb C$ is impossible.